# Change spread of x axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to spread out one part of an x-axis and shrink another part of it in ggplot? I'm plotting up some climate data from the 1980s and projected out till 2100. The observed portion of the data is scrunched up, while there's a bunch of room in the 2030-2100 projections. Year (x axis) is numeric.

```
avgoverlap_flounder=ggplot(data=flounder.overlap, aes(x=year, y=mean, color=prey)) + 
geom_ribbon(data=mean.overlap.flounder.shrimp, aes(x = year, ymin = lci, ymax = uci), inherit.aes = FALSE,fill = "midnightblue", alpha=0.3) +
geom_ribbon(data=mean.overlap.flounder.pollock, aes(x = year,ymin = lci, ymax = uci), inherit.aes = FALSE,fill = "firebrick4", alpha=0.3)  + 
geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c("firebrick4", "midnightblue")) + 
labs(y = "Area Overlap", x="Year") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.title=element_blank()) +
ggtitle("Arrowtooth flounder") + 
theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the way it is plotted now the desired behavior? People expect the x-axis to be linear. To compress the timeline would easily mislead the viewer into thinking the future changes would happen faster than the prediction says.